# Can an empty URL parameter be passed to my controller?

Tags: codeigniter, url, parameter-passing

Let's say my controller function is expecting 2 parameters: page_name, and user_name

The URL would be in the format http://mysite.com/controller_name/function_name/page_name/user_name

Assuming that sometimes I can have a blank user_name, and other times I can have blank page_name, can I pass a blank page_name by loading this URL?
http://mysite.com/controller_name/function_name//user_name

If the controller function is:

```
function function_name($page_name="default", $user_name=null) 
...
```

Would the $page_name value be "default" for the 2nd URL stated above?

Comment: For better control, you should have another function to user_name exclusive: function_name2/user_name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Server will simply ignore the extra slash.
Since both parameters are optional, you should use request parameters.
http://mysite.com/controller_name/function_name?page_name=p1&user_name=u1

And in your controller, use `$this->input->get('page_name')` and `$this->input->get('user_name')` to get the value and check if the values are empty.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but the solution I came up with is simple.  It goes something like this:

```
$this->input->get('limit') ? $this->input->get('limit') : 20;
```